# How to get actual screen size after Android N?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

Since Android N introduces split screen, the window size of your app can be half of the original. I found that `getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);` no longer always returns the actual device screen size anymore because in split screen mode the display's height will be your app's window height instead. Is there any other API I can use to get the actual screen size?

Comment: Why do you want the actual screen size?

Comment: "the window size of your app can be half of the original" -- once we start getting devices that support freeform multi-window mode, your window size can be a lot less than half of the screen.

Comment: @ianhanniballake well say you have an utility app that tells you about your device screen size, (width, height, diagonal), or apps that try to collect/log users' device screen size data. I'm just curious if there an alternative easy way to do it with android N

Answer (score 3):

[`Display.getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealMetrics(android.util.DisplayMetrics)) will return the actual display size.

Comment: Having a method in the core API that starts with `getReal` for this long is really troubling. We really need to clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get real device size in Multi-Window Mode using `Display` or `DisplayMetrics`.

**Using Display:**

```
private void findRealSize(Activity activity)
{
    Point size = new Point();
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
        display.getRealSize(size);
    else
        display.getSize(size);

    int realWidth = size.x;
    int realHeight = size.y;

    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "realWidth: " + realWidth + " realHeight: " + realHeight);
}
```

**Using DisplayMetrics:**

```
private void findRealSize(Activity activity)
{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
    {
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }
    else
    {
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }

    int realWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int realHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "realWidth: " + realWidth + " realHeight: " + realHeight);
}
```

Comment: I am using SDK API 30, and the getRealSize and getSize will return DIFFERENT answers.  The getReal is giving the true hardware size, but the getSize is smaller. It subtracts the size of the action bar.

Answer (score -2):

By the moment I couldn't find a proper solution for that at all, but I'm handling it by the densityDpi of every resolution which is changed. Just like this:

```
private int getScreenDensityDPI() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
    } else {
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    }
    return metrics.densityDpi;
}

private int getNumberItemsByScreenResolution() {
    int densityDPI = getScreenDensityDPI();
    if (densityDPI <= 140) {
        return 6;
    } else if (densityDPI <= 160) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

While lowest the densityDPI is, highest the resolution of the display will be in your android N device.